# how to dynamically call icons on images in MVC 4 razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I want to call icons dynamically on images. like flight, meals, contact. and different images have different icon in MVC 4 razor view  how can i do this please help me.

```
@{
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i += 3)
    {
        j = i;
        <div class="row">
            @while (j < i + 3 && j < Model.Count())
            {
                <div class=" col-sm-4" style="position:relative">
                    <a href="@Model[j].NavUrl" style="text-decoration:none">
                        <img src="data:image/png;base64,@Convert.ToBase64String(Model[j].ImageData,0,Model[j].ImageData.Length)" width="100%" height="200px" />

                        <p style="position: absolute;top: 127px; width: 100%; background: rgba(28, 108, 157, 0.79); color: #fff; padding: 10px; width: 243px; font-size: 13px;"><span>Starting Price  <i class="fa fa-rupee"></i>  </span>@Html.DisplayFor(Modelj => Model[j].PackageCost)<span>*</span>/Person</p>
                        <p style="font-size:medium;  color:black">@Html.DisplayFor(Modelj => Model[j].PackageName)</p>

                        <p class="package-desc">@Html.DisplayFor(Modelj => Model[j].imageDescription)</p>

                    </a>
        </div>
                j++;
            }
        </div>
    }

}
```

Comment: Show us the code of your view file ... It is impossible to help you otherwise ...

Comment: i showed my view @ EluciusFTW

Comment: Pass those image urls as part of your Model and use that. What problem are you facing ?

Comment: I got the ans Thanks all of you